How get OpnSense to work as a dynamic dns with a NameCheap domain?
I have a domain from NameCheap and I'm running the latest OpnSense on my router, but trying to set up the DynDns gives me an error in my log file:
   <ResponseString>Validation error; not found; domain name(s)</ResponseString> 
   <ResponseNumber>316153</ResponseNumber>  
   <Description>Domain name not found</Description>

I've seen other people having this problem, but nothitg comprehensive as a guide.

There are quite a few steps to getting NameCheap domain working as a dyndns with OpnSense:
Let's say you want to use the domain example.com

You need to get a "Dynamic DNS Password" for your domain (remember you are creating a password for @.example.com
Then you need to create an "A+ Dynamic DNS Record" for your record
Then install "DdClient" in OpnSense
Then create account in Services>DynDns tab.

For the service use "NameCheap"
For the username use the name of your domain (e.g. "example.com")
For the password use the password from step #1
For the Hostname(s) use "@" your domain name so @.example.com not "example.com", the "@" is important or you'll get an error with No Records updated. A record not Found;
For the "Check ip method" you'll probably want Interface which means get the IP to name the domain to from the IP on your ethernet/wireless card
Select the Interface to monitor which is in the case of having multiple ethernet cards. If "WAN" is an option, you probably want that one.


Then save and apply. You can get the log

